# Custom Post Type - after disable 'Add New', I can't edit and delete post

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, capabilities

I need to disable 'Add New' button for my CPT, but when I add:

```
'capabilities' => array(
    'create_posts' => false,
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'edit_post' => true,
    'delete_post' => true,
),
```

I can only VIEW this post (I can't edit and delete it) - why?

Answer (score 1):

Full credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16675677/988246) on Stack Overflow: you need to set the `create_posts` value to `do_not_allow` (or `false` in Wordpress versions below 4.5) and crucially set the `map_meta_cap` to `true`:

```
register_post_type( 'custom_post_type_name', array(
    'capability_type' => 'post',
        'capabilities' => array(
        'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow', // Prior to Wordpress 4.5, this was false
    ),
    'map_meta_cap' => true, //  With this set to true, users will still be able to edit & delete posts
));
```